# Regex expression for IP exclude Network and broadcast address in Javascript

Tags: regex, regex-group

Hi I have to write a regex which validates all the IPs except the Network and broadcast address.

For eg:
I want only the ips which are not like xxx.xxx.xxx.0 or xxx.xxx.xxx.255

```
(((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-4]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))(?![\\d])([,\s]+|$))*
```

This is the regex I wrote.
It doesnt validate xxx.xxx.xxx.255 but it validates for xxx.xxx.xxx.0

What can I do. I tried negative look aheads and behinds but it doesn't work.

I have come up with this

```
(((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-4]|2[0-4][0-9]|(?=([1]?[0-9][0-9]?){2,3})[1]?[0-9][0-9]?|[1-9]))(?![\\d])([,\s]+|$))*
```

Will this be the exact one?